# How to use HttpGet in ASP.NET Core dynamic web api?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, aspnetboilerplate, http-verbs

How to accept Verbs(Get) in ASP.NET Core dynamic web api？

**Before**

ABP(.NetFramework)

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().DynamicApiControllerBuilder
.For<ITaskAppService>("tasksystem/task")
.ForMethod("GetTasks").WithVerb(HttpVerb.Get)
.Build();
```

**New**

ABP(ASP.NET Core)

- You can use RemoteService attribute to enable/disable it for method
  or class level.

I don't know how to use RemoteService attribute, do you have any example code?

- You can use any ASP.NET Core attributes to change HTTP methods or
  routes of the actions (but surely, this requires to add reference to
  related ASP.NET Core package).

I can't add Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core to ABP 2.0.2 (ASP.NET Core),
so I can't use [HttpGet].

Almost APIs use PostRequest, but need a little GetRequest for third-party.
Thanks.

Ref:
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/AspNet-Core#application-services-as-controllers

Answer (score 1):

Add [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/1.1.5) package instead.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core;

public class TaskAppService : ITaskAppService
{
    [HttpGet]
    public void MyMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

You should add the corresponding version of the package:

- v1.1.5 for ASP.NET Core 1.x
- v2.0.1 for ASP.NET Core 2.x